# Nothing is showing up in Canvas Area when PIXI bundle is used with snowpack

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js, snowpack

I have installed a template from below command for my First PIXI Typescript project, as below:

```
npx create-snowpack-app . --template @snowpack/app-template-blank-typescript --force
```

Now after installing and clearing its default code. I have installed few more packages as below

package.json as below:

```
{
  "scripts": {
  "start": "snowpack dev",
  "build": "snowpack build"
},
"dependencies": {
  "canvas-confetti": "^1.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@snowpack/plugin-typescript": "^1.2.1",
  "@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.0.0",
  "@types/snowpack-env": "^2.3.3",
  "pixi.js": "^7.2.4",
  "pixijs": "^7.1.4",
  "prettier": "^2.2.1",
  "snowpack": "^3.3.7",
  "typescript": "^4.2.4"
 }
}
```

and in ts file i am just draewing a PIXI Rectangle

```
public constructor() {
 this.app = new PIXI.Application();

this.app.renderer.background.color = 0x23395D;
this.app.renderer.background.alpha = 1;
const rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.beginFill(0xAA33BB)
.drawRect(200, 200, 100, 120)
.endFill();
this.app.stage.addChild(rect);
}
```

And index.html code is simple, which is as below:

```
<style>
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  touch-action: none;
  cursor: default;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

But when i run the code then i can found the Graphics in Chrome PIXI tool, But its not showing me at all. I checked the same in Edge Browser as well. So please help me in this.